# iOS - Aggregating scraped data in a unique way, will I be rejected?

Tags: ios, screen-scraping, appstore-approval

I am building some services that will scrape data from a number of websites and be stored into a database. I am then using services to call this data into an iOS app and display it in an organized manner that will be useful to users. Will my app be rejected due to this policy?

> 12.3
>
> Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a
>   collection of links, may be rejected

I am not using any child browser, etc. When a user views the data within the app they may click a link to go to the specific webpage in Safari separately, but there is no "Buy" button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're adding some value to the content I don't think you have a problem.  Look at Flipbook; it basically rehashes people's web data, but it a useful way.  Aggregation itself isn't bad, it's people who don't put an effort to curate or correlate the data is where I believe Apple has a problem.

tl;dr: It depends on how you implement your app.